# Moving from docker ce to docker-EE

Tags: docker, docker-engine, docker-ee

I have built all my micro services on a **docker-ce** engine and got all the system running with Kubernetes.

Now I want to start working with **docker-EE** and from what I have read I couldn't understand if I will be able to use all my images with the new **docker-EE** as my docker engine?

Comment: if your new docker setup is on the same cpu architecture there shouldnt be any problems

Comment: Docker EE is based on Docker CE, so I *do not* think that you will have any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all my images that were built over the **docker-ce** engine on a **docker-EE** engine (running on RHLE7.5), it validates that it is possible to Move from **docker-ce** to **docker-EE**.

As mentioned in the above comments:

your new docker setup should be on the same CPU architecture.